# ArcSde for Sql Server 2014 enterprise

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I Want to Add Database Server in ArcCatalog. My Database is Sql Server 2014 enterprise;When I try, It returns that "Connections to this edition of the database Server are not Supported". I Searched and found that i should install proper version of Arcsde. But I couldnt find ArcSde for Sql Server 2014 enterprise. How can solve this problem?
(ArcGis 10.2.2 ; Sql Server 2014 enterprise; Sql Client is installed;)

Comment: ArcSDE no longer exists. Look at the system requirements for *enterprise database* support, but I doubt 2014 was supported by 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2014 is supported with ArcGIS 10.2.2, but with some caveats:

1. You cannot use Native Client 11. You need to install SQL Server Native Client 2012 on your client machine;
2. Your SQL Server instance must be 64 bit.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//015100000070000000

When you use the term "Database Server", are you referring to a workgroup geodatabase? These are installed within SQL Server Express databases. I don't think you want to do that:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/database-servers/arcgis-database-servers.htm

You're probably clicking the wrong folder in ArcCatalog. Instead of right-clicking "Add Database Server", right-click "Add Database Connection" to connect to an enterprise workspace.